# Dadas dos cadenas, ¿cómo obtener la cadena de mayor y menor longitud?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Dado 2 cadenas quiero devolver una cadena que sea el resultado de concatenar la cadena menor más la cadena mayor y más la cadena menor.

```
 def combo_string(a, b):
  mini = min(a, b)
  maxi = max(a, b)
  return mini + maxi + mini
```

Probé la función y retorna una cadena donde está la cadena mayor primero concatenada con la cadena menor y concatenada con la mayor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que tanto [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#max) como [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#min) retornan el máximo o mínimo de las cadenas indicadas según el orden alfabético pero nada tiene que ver con las longitudes de las mismas.

Ejemplo:

```
print(max('AAAAA', 'B'))
B
```

Para hacer lo que buscas podrías resolverlo de esta forma:

```
def combo_string(a, b):
  mini = a if len(a) <= len(b) else b
  maxi = a if len(a) > len(b) else b
  return mini + maxi + mini
```

Usamos un operador ternario preguntando por la longitud de cada cadena. así asignamos la variable correspondiente.

Answer (score 2):

`min` y `max` no tienen en cuenta la longitud de las cadenas, tienen en cuenta el orden lexicográfico. En todo caso, si quieres usar esta aproximación, debes usar `max` y `min` sobre la salida de `len` , cosa que puedes hacer usando el argumento `key`:

```
mini = min(a, b, key=len)
maxi = max(a, b, key=len)
```

o puedes usar directamente `sorted`:

```
mini, maxi = sorted((a, b), key=len)
```

`key` permite indicar a `min`, `max`, `sorted` y  `list.sort` que debe tener en cuenta para ordenar los ítems, en este caso a la hora de ordenar usa el retorno de `len(cad)`, es decir la longitud de cada cadena.

La concatenación de cadenas es ineficiente dada su inmutabilidad (en cada concatenación se ha de crear una cadena nueva que luego a de ser eliminada por el GC), siempre que concatenes más de dos considera  usas  `str.join` o literales de cadena formateados en Python >= 3.6

```
def combo_string(a, b):
    mini, maxi = sorted((a, b), key=len)
    return f"{mini}{maxi}{mini}" # return "".join((mini, maxi, mini))
```

Si ambas cadenas tiene por casualidad la misma longitud, se mantiene simplemente el orden inicial:

> >>> combo_string("bbb", "cc")
>   'ccbbbcc'
>
> >>> combo_string("cc", "bb")
>   'ccbbcc'
>
> >>> combo_string("bb", "cc")
>   'bbccbb'

De cualquier manera, la forma más eficiente para el resultado concreto que quieres en este caso es usar un simple `if`:

```
def combo_string(a, b):
    if len(a) > len(b):
        a, b = b, a
    return f"{a}{b}{a}" # return "".join((a, b, a))
```

o directamente:

```
def combo_string(a, b):
    return f"{b}{a}{b}" if len(a) > len(b) else f"{a}{b}{a}"
```